# SMS auto-responses on Android

Tags: android, sms, voice, auto-responder

First, a non-programming question:  My phone is auto-responding to missed calls with a text message: "Sorry. I'm not near my phone right now."  Where did my phone get the idea to do that and how do I make it stop?

And a programming question:  How can I make my Android do arbitrary things in response to a missed call, such as email me the phone number, or just customize the SMS auto-response, perhaps replying with my location.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to your programming question:

Setup an IntentListener for incoming calls. If it's not answered, have your application process it accordingly!

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that I had installed an Android Market app called dgAway that does SMS auto-responses.  I had never run that app nor checked the "auto-respond to missed calls" box, but it seems that may have been what was doing the auto-responses.  I tried uninstalling it and the auto-responses seem to have stopped.

ADDED: I found a really nice Android app, DroidTracker, that will (for approved contacts) auto-reply with your location when the contact texts you a phrase of your choosing (eg, "where are you?" or "ping").  You can also set a less guessable phrase (default is "I want my phone back") that will cause your phone to auto-respond to *anyone*, approved or not.  That way if your phone is lost or stolen you can ask your phone where it is.